# NSTimer countdown label

Tags: iphone, nstimer

It will keep counting down and updating the current time. Anyone has any idea how to approach this problem? I don't see how the NStimer will recognize the date format like this: 
20110803 23:59:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can specify a format string (`-[setDateFormat:]`)that lets you convert to AND from `NSDate` and `NSString`.

When converting back to your countdown view, you may want to use `NSDateComponents` and [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) to get the pieces you need for your countdown label (instead of `NSDateFormatter`). You could do something like:

```
NSDateComponents *countdown = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
    components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) 
      fromDate:[NSDate date] 
        toDate:expiration 
       options:0];
```

This will calculate all the unit differences for you (with respect to the device's currently configured calendar settings).

You can get the components back with a call like `[countdown day]` or `[countdown hour]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date easily by using `NSDateFormatter` like this to get a `NSDate` object from your string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd' 'HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:your_date_string];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the date from NSString to NSDate by using the NSDateformatter class.

```
NSString *dateString = @"20110803 23:59:59";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Now, in order to count down, you use the `NSTimer` class to fire every one second, then you can get the difference in seconds between the current date and your `date`variable by simply use `timeIntervalSinceDate`.

```
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:yourDate];
```

Now that you have the difference in seconds, you convert it to whatever format you wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't drill down into this problem deeply, therefore sorry, if my answer is a bit unappropriate.

In this case I would use NSDate. Using NSDateFormatter I would convert text data of xml to NSDate. Changing the value of NSDate, when every tick of NSTimer, properly.
And a bit of code, 'cause the symbols of NSDateFormatter sometimes create mess:

```
    NSString *xmlDateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:xmlDateFormat];
    NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStringFromXml];
```

This is for reading from xml. For changing value of NSDate when tick you can see the doc of NSDate. And for display the value in label I would arithmetically calculate every value and show it with the help of casual NSString:

```
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dday %dh %dm %ds", days, hours, minutes, seconds];
```